How cookie domain and section is determined
I am trying to understand about cookies in depth .
When I visit any page , for reference when I visited youtube , I gets following cookie .

I have two queries highlighted in different colors

Yellow highlight -- what is the meaning of multiple domain within cookie being shown here ? for ex - I visited only youtube but I see two section which is youtube.com and accounts.youtube.com ( in some cases it is totally different top level domain ).   Can we set something like it from website code , if yes then looking for an example ?

Purple Highlight -- I visited youtube but I see google cookie as well . Who exactly is setting google related cookie ? Is a request being send to google.com from youtube and then google is setting this cookie in response ? Also , How can I achieve this with code ?


